# Loading Facebook Images in the background to save to Core Data on the main thread

Tags: facebook, image, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I am loading Facebook images. I am trying to use the code below to return an image so that I can save it to the record of a 'Friend' object using Core Data. It isn't working.. nothing gets returned. Is there any way to load the data in the background and then create the image on the main queue, and return it? I need my image created on the main queue because I want to save it to my object with my app delegate's managed object context.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageForObject:(NSString *)objectID {

    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=%d&height=%d",objectID,IMAGE_MAXWIDTH,IMAGE_MAXHEIGHT];
    __block UIImage *image;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        });
    });
    return image;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible to load images in the background, but not like this. This method is designed so that it's really impossible for it to *not* return nil. When you call `dispatch_async`, it returns immediately and finishes its work asynchronously. That's why it has "async" right in its name. You code reaches `return image;` before you've loaded the image.

You're on the right track, though. The usual approach is to dispatch back to the main queue when the background work is finished. But when doing that, it's impossible for a method like yours to return the image. If it did, the main queue would have to wait around until the image was loaded, which defeats the whole purpose of running on a background queue.

What you should do instead is:

1. In your `dispatch_async` back to the main queue, do whatever work you need to do with the image-- show it on the screen, or write it to a file, or whatever it is you need to do with the image.
2. Make your method return `void`, since it can't return the image directly to the caller. Or if you like, make it return `BOOL` to indicate whether the image load was started. But it can't return the `UIImage` unless you make the main queue wait on the image-- which as I mentioned, defeats the whole purpose of using background queues.

Comment: thanks Tom, that is a great answer. I actually have an activity indicator running purposefully, as I am importing and am fine to make the user wait because they can see they are waiting. I would do it in the background, but I have no idea how to save in the background successfully (yet). I am only using the app delegate managed object context throughout the app, something I know I have to change. But I cannot find one good solid example of saving in the background, except for an article on CIMGF that basically points to using Magical Record. Everyone seems to do it differently..

Comment: I do have one question though - I found that I can save the image in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) if I pass in the proper parameters. Can you confirm that if I ever did end up creating and setting the image there that it would have been created in my main managedObjectContext (app delegate) and I would not have a problem when saving?

Comment: Also can you tell me more about returning bool? when would it do that? It seems like something that could be very useful. And if I have an activity indicator running, why do I even need to do this in the background at all? The assertions are killing me...

Comment: Even if you think it's OK to have the user wait, you really, really don't want to do this on the main queue. Your UI will be completely non-responsive while the download happens, making it seem like your app has crashed. The usual approach with background queues is to use multiple managed object contexts. It's also possible to dispatch back to the main queue to save. Even better is to use queue confinement and either `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` on the MOC.

Comment: So, the dispatch_get_main_queue is definitely "thread safe" for saving on the main app (delegate) managedObjectContext. I can create an object there and later save the main appdelegate MOC with no problem.... okay, I get that now. But I don't understand why I wouldn't want to display the activity indicator and stop view interaction when the Facebook friends are importing. The import will completely change the entire UI, not one small part of it. I don't want the user to do anything else, as it might interfere. Am I missing something here (it is very likely that I am.)

Comment: Blocking the UI for any perceptible length of time is extremely poor user experience. Users may think the app has crashed, for example. Better to show a placeholder image while downloading in the background and then update the UI when it's ready. Also, please, for your own sake, look into queue confinement, `performBlock`, and `performBlockAndWait`.

Comment: I will Tom thanks. Just FYI, I am not just importing images, but creating an entire object based on each Friend imported. So the user is looking at a blank list, they hit the plus button to import from Facebook, select a bunch of friends, hit Done. Then they are returned to their blank list? Not trying to be obtuse, but explanatory. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: And I WILL be looking into queue confinement, performBlock, and performBlockAndWait.

Comment: That sounds fine, just don't ever block the main queue for longer than absolutely necessary.